# Facebook requesting missing permissions

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

I've created my first Facebook app and I need to have publish_stream permission. I can easily check for it by looping through each permission gained and seeing if its there but if user denies it what can I do using PHP?

The app is embedded inside facebook as "canvas app" or whatever its called. I know how can I request more permissions in external site by giving login url with new permissions but I got no idea how could I possibly do it inside app?

I've googled and googled but all I can find is how to get login url with permissions.. I even tried it but nothing happened as I was already logged in.

Heres the code I tried:

```
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,user_likes',
            'next' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
            'cancel_url' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
        ));

        echo "<a href='" . $loginUrl . "'>login</a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how can I request more permissions in external site by giving login url with new permissions but I got no idea how could I possibly do it inside app?

Basically just the same way – by calling the Auth dialog with an appropriate scope parameter.

What you are doing wrong in your sample code is just that you are linking to the dialog’s URL within your app’s iframe – but the Auth dialog does not permit being displayed in an iframe. Add `target="_top"` to the link, then the Auth dialog will actually show up. (You will also have to set the `redirect_uri` parameter to the address of your app on Facebook, something like `https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE`.)

Of course you could also use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK instead – that will show the Auth dialog as a popup.